# How can I extend entity generated by Entity Framework but not map it to the DB column

Tags: c#, entity-framework

My situation is:
1. I have entity model generated by EF via model designer.
2. Database is generated by EF via model designer as well.
2. All of the entities' properties are mapped to the DB columns respectively.
   For e.g. my generated "problematic" entity is:

```
[EdmEntityTypeAttribute(NamespaceName="MyModel", Name="File")]
[Serializable()]
[DataContractAttribute(IsReference=true)]
public partial class File : ContentItem
{
    //some properties

    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=false)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public global::System.Int32 Major
    {
        // get and set are here
    }

    //another properties
}
```

I need:
1. Extend entity manually with one scalar property (create partial class in the same namespace as generated);
   What I've done:

```
public partial class File
{
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public double ContextWeight { get; set; }
}
```

2. This new "ContextWeight" property will be calculated and initialized when service executes specific functionality. Then I need this property available on the client (proxy).

Problem:
When I build service project and then update service reference to it in the Client(proxy) project, then on the Client(proxy) I don't see this new property existing in File class.

Note: I don't need "ContextWeight" property map to any DB column.

Could you please advise what should I add (maybe some attributes are missing or whatever)?